# Establish a relation between p and q

Tags: inequality

For positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, ... ,a_{100}$, let $$p = \sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i $$ and $$q = \sum_{1\le i \lt j \le 100} a_ia_j \space .$$ Then establish an inequality(or equality) among $p$ and $q$.

Will the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality work in some modified form here?

Answer (score 1):

The well-known identity is that: $p^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + 2q \Rightarrow p^2 \geq \dfrac{p^2}{n} + 2q \Rightarrow np^2 \geq p^2 + 2nq \Rightarrow (n-1)p^2 \geq 2nq$.